# subsetting data frame based on search pattern in vector

Tags: r

I've spent a few hours on a problem with subsetting data frame rows based on search pattern in a vector. I'm newbie in R. Maybe it's easy, but I can't do it myself, and I can't find a solution in stackoverflow

Suppose that I've a mtcars data from R.

I want to subset rows with a few cars name for example only Mazda, Ford and Chevrolet. So I have a character vector car.names with names of cars I want to subset:

```
car.names <- c("Mazda", "Ford", "Chevrolet")
```

Question is: How to subset mtcars rows based on criteria in car.names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alexwhan's answer is the way I would approach this too, but I thought I would share this answer in case it is helpful for others: You can consider using `Vectorize` to create a "vectorized" version of `grep`:

```
vGrep <- Vectorize(grep, vectorize.args="pattern")
```

Here's what the output looks like:

```
vGrep(car.names, rownames(mtcars))
# $Mazda
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $Ford
# [1] 29
# 
# $Chevrolet
# integer(0)
```

You can `unlist` the output to use the values to subset from your `data.frame`:

```
mtcars[unlist(vGrep(car.names, rownames(mtcars))), ]
#                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Ford Pantera L 15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
```

Comment: Thank you Ananda your answer is very good because in my case I prefer to have pattern in vector. Thanks once more

Comment: @sms, thanks for the accept, but I think @alexwhan's answer is actually the more common way. You can automatically create the search pattern from your vector with `paste(car.names, collapse = "|")`. Thus, for a complete solution, you would do: `mtcars[grep(paste(car.names, collapse = "|"), rownames(mtcars)), ]`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are wanting to combine a `grep` search with indexing. Here's I would approach it for `mtcars`:

```
car.names <- "Mazda|Ford|Chevrolet"
filtered <- mtcars[grepl(car.names, rownames(mtcars)),]
filtered
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Ford Pantera L 15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was sure that it must be done with grepl but my misteake was in creating vector.