# R -- Is there a code way to do the R search?

Tags: r, twitter

At the top of my data frame window, there is a search box. When I search through my tweet column "Trump", it pulls up all the tweets containing Trump.

Is there a way to do this search by code?

I want to create a variable such that

```
All_Twitter_Data$Keyword_Trump <- 0 
All_Twitter_Data$Keyword_Trump[ **SUBSET OF TWEETS THAT CONTAIN TRUMP** ] <-1
```

Edit 1:

```
All_Twitter_Data$Keyword_Trump <- 0 
All_Twitter_Data$Keyword_Trump[grepl("Trump", ignore.case=TRUE, fixed=TRUE)] <-1
```

returns

```
Error in grepl("Trump", ignore.case = TRUE, fixed = TRUE) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Edit 2: (based on the duplicate)

```
vGrep <- Vectorize(All_Twitter_Data, vectorize.args="Trump")
```

returns

```
Error in Vectorize(All_Twitter_Data, vectorize.args = "Trump") : 
    must specify names of formal arguments for 'vectorize'
```

Comment: replace `**stuf**` with `grepl("Trump", ignore.case=TRUE, fixed=TRUE)` probably.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a good dupe, [subsetting data frame based on search pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20440915/903061) is okay, but there's probably a better one out there.

Comment: @lmo tried it and there was an error. posted an update so u can see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subsetting data frame based on search pattern in vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440915/subsetting-data-frame-based-on-search-pattern-in-vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the variables I was looking for:

```
df$Keyword_Column <- 0 
df$Keyword_Column[grep(as.character(df$text_column),ignore.case=TRUE, pattern=paste0("insertword"))] <-1
```

This returns a count:

```
# count word frequency
wordfreq <- function(data, word) {
  results <- lapply(data,
                    function(x) { grep(as.character(x),
                    ignore.case=TRUE, pattern=paste0(word)) }
  )
  sum(unlist(results))
}
```